# Deploy Vue JS Django app with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got an app I've built locally and I'm ready to deploy it but using Vue as a frontend and Django as the backend is something new to me. My current folder structure looks like:

> -Backend
>   -Frontend
>   -Env

The backend folder is a traditional Django project with sqlite as a DB and frontend is your normal looking Vue project while env is the virtual environment

I don't even know how to go about this or what questions to ask but I've come to see that people deploy SPAs with AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

What is the most straightforward way to deploy an app like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way we often use

If you are accessing your Django project using ajax call

1.Create the build of your project

2. Once your build is created you need to host this build to some URL using s3 or any other preferred static hosting.
3. Now you need to deploy your Django project using EB, once you deploy your project you will get an autogenerated URL
4. In your frontend project, you need to set an environment variable in your configuration so that whenever you build a project all you ajax call will be redirected to the elastic beanstalk auto-generated URL and whenever you are working locally all your call will be redirected to the localhost URL

Below coded is not the exact just a rough idea of what exactly your baseurl should look like

```
env.APILINK=env.build? 'beanstalkurl':'localhost'
```

Make sure you add a base URL to you axios or any other ajax call,
once you set your baseurl based on the environment you are working, all the ajax call will be redirected accordingly

For the dev environment

```
http://localhost/api/getsomedata
```

For the prod environment which is actually a build

```
http://beanstalkurl/api/getsomedata
```

Comment: Is it possible to deploy both django and vue apps to same eb instance. I know that eb supports multicontainers in one instance. What I'd like to do is to deploy both BE and FE to the same instance actually, is that possible or do I have to deploy my Vue app to another instance?